# Is there any significance in Capt. Jack Sparrow being called Mr. Smith in the first Pirates of the Carribean?

Tags: character, pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

So in the first Pirates of the Caribbean, The Curse of the Black Pearl, when Jack Sparrow first arrives at the port, the man asks him for a schilling and his name in order to "tie up his boat" in the dock. Jack Sparrow gives him 3 schillings instead in hopes for remaining nameless. As Jack Sparrow walks away, the man calls him "Mr. Smith".

Also, later when he is talking to the two guards at the boat, just before Elizabeth Swan falls from the ledge into the water, the guards ask him his name and he replies "Smith".

Is there any significance in this in the fact that he is referenced to as and references himself as Smith, since the first mate that he recruits for his quest is Arabella Smith, the daughter of the infamous pirate Laura Smith? Or is this just a mere coincidence?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure if it has some special significance in this particular instance, but "Smith" is one of the most common surnames in the US, perhaps even the most common. So when someone wants to pick a pseudonym to mask their true identity, it's a typical choice. And for some reason, "Smith" has acquired this reputation more than any other common surname, so you'll frequently see it used for that purpose in TV and movies.

Comment: As illustrated in Marty Feldman's "The Last Remake of Beau Geste": https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=KzIJSUwcFdw#t=1446

Comment: Totally agree, and would also add that "John" is the common accompaniment to that surname. Therefore, "John Smith" would be the most common "fake" name used (probably due to the popularity of both names).

Comment: It's more relevant that it was one of the most common surnames in England and its colonies at that time. I mean, the US didn't even _exist_ yet...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true, though I think it's more relevant that the movie was primarily targeted at an American audience.

Comment: @David: That would be strange, seeing as there are more people not in America than in America. Indeed, [it grossed more internationally than domestically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_The_Curse_of_the_Black_Pearl#Box_office) and it's hard to imagine that anyone in the marketing department did not expect that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't claim that there were more people in the US than out of it, nor that the movie made most of its money domestically. I said that the movie was primarily targeted at an American audience. (To be fair, I don't know offhand that this is true, but I strongly suspect it is, and that the same applies to most major American films.)

Comment: @David: I know what you said; I'm suggesting that it _wasn't_ primarily targeted at an American audience because that would be really silly. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I believe you're wrong about that - I strongly suspect the movie was targeted at an American audience (to be clear, I mean to the extent it was targeted at all), and furthermore, I don't believe it's silly to do so. But I suppose it doesn't really matter for this answer.

Comment: @DavidZ: I just pointed out some very good reasons that it would be silly :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "That would be strange, seeing as there are more people not in America than in America." You are factually correct, and I agree with you that this is a good reason to not bias yourself towards American audiences. But you can't deny that there is a **heavy** bias towards American audiences for most media. Even just posting on the internet, the assumption is often that the poster is from America (whenever someone assumes my nationality online, it's always American. Never anything else)

Comment: @Flater: _"Even just posting on the internet, the assumption is often that the poster is from America"_ I've seen this assumption come from Americans but not from anyone else. The rest of us understand that other places exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've had it happen with other nationalities too, but Americans are the most prone to it, yes. I'm not American, and I even fall into the trap myself from time to time (if their post does not reveal or hint at a non-American point of view or word usage)

Comment: @Flater: Surprised a Belgian would assume an American audience! To each their own I suppose.. :)

Comment: was port Royal has any connection to US? at that time period? you said *"Smith" is one of the most common surnames in the US*

Answer (score 4):

Adding something here,

When Jack first arrives at Port Royale, following conversation happens with harbormaster and Jack.

> > Harbormaster: Hold up there, you. It's a shilling to tie up your boat at the dock... and I shall need to know your name.
> >
> > Jack Sparrow: What do you say to three shillings and we forget the name.
> >
> > Harbormaster: Welcome to Port Royal, Mr. Smith.

Being *Smith* is very common and widely used name at that time, similar concept used just like hide something in a plain sight.

So Jack accepts that and he kept using name *Smith* to hide himself from others while appearing publicly.

**Update..**

In *Pirates of the Caribbean : on Stranger Tides* Jack impersonates a judge and he is also called as "Honorable judge Smith", This couldn't be a mere co-incidence.

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered names like Smith and Jones are so common that they are often used as an alias, which is case with Captain Jack Sparrow docking on Port Royal...

However, the name Smith tends to be **a thematic reoccurring name throughout the entire work**...

1. Smith, like many surnames was once an occupational surname referring to either **a lock smith or a black smith**. So there's a bit of irony that Jack's fate would become entangled with the son of a former comrade, whose profession is a black smith. (Will Turner II)
2. In young Jack Sparrow adventure novels, Jack Sparrow is friends with a girl of similar age named [Arabella Smith](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Arabella_Smith). There are also her parents, a Pirate named Laura Smith, and Laura's husband was a tavern owner of *The Faithful Bride*...
3. *In Pirates of the Caribbean On Stranger Tides*, Jack impersonates the real [Justice Smith](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Smith_(judge)), whose been tied up and gagged.
4. In the fifth film '*Dead Man Tell No Tales'*, we are introduced to [Carina Smyth](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Carina_Smyth), with her surname being a variation of Smith. In addition she is an astronomer who uses a gemstone, stars, under a blood moon to navigate and this juxtaposes a magical object known as the Sun-and-Stars Amulet that Arabella uses in the young Jack Sparrow Novels. The Trident also derives from the young Jack Sparrow Novels.

Answer (score 0):

The harbormaster is indicating that he has accepted the bribe and will allow Jack to remain anonymous. He may also be slyly suggesting that he thinks Jack is up to no good. Giving the name of Smith when registering at a public accommodation is strongly associated in the public imagination with devious behavior.

For example, it is the name which adulterers supposedly write in hotel registers. Groucho Marx got a lot of mileage out of this in *A Night in Casablanca*. His character is working at the reception desk of a hotel when a Mr. and Mrs. Smith try to register. He loudly expresses the belief that "with a name like Smith" they can't possibly really be married.